make one argument of a function optional in ES6
I have built a function to call fetch with all the parameters I require set up. It works flawlessly but I want to improve it a bit. Currently I have two versions of it, one for GET and another for POST method. This is because for POST I need to pass a body while for GET no. I'd like to make it so that the body parameter in the function becomes optional and included in fetch only if set if it is a GET request.
This is the relevant part in case of GET
async function getData(url = "") {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: "GET",
            mode: "cors",
            credentials: "include",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
        });

this is the relevant part in case of POST
async function postData(url = "", data = {}) {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            mode: "cors",
            credentials: "include",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data), 
        });


Parameters are always optional in JavaScript; it's not clear what you're asking. What is it that you think you cannot do?

@Pointy good to know about the parameters. But when it comes to await fetch(url, {... the body property should be there only if it is post. And that's something I don't know how to do

You can check the "method" and see whether it's GET or POST. In my experience if you set the body in a fetch() call to undefined then a GET will be happy. I guess you're really asking, how do you leave off the "body" property altogether for a GET?  You'd have to build the fetch parameter object as a separate step, then add the body if it's a POST.

write a third function, and call that one with the method and the potential body in case of post, and spread those arguments into your fetch options

@Pointy that is what I was trying to understand how to achieve. I add the body part only if method is POST and voila. So I don't even need to set the body as undefined

I guess you could simply write a third function that does a send
like:


function send(url, options) {
  if (!url) {
    throw 'url not specified';
  }
  return fetch( url, {
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    ...options });
}

function getData(url) {
  return send( url, { method: 'GET' });
}

function postData(url, body) {
  return post( url, { method: 'POST', body: body ? JSON.stringify( body ) : null });
}



this would allow you to add more methods afterwards and keeps the headers logic in one place
